# Refresh token with Redux Toolkit Query

Tags: rtk-query

First of all I'll start with the snippet that you can find on rtk official documentation webpage.

```js
import { fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { tokenReceived, loggedOut } from './authSlice'

const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' })
const baseQueryWithReauth = async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  let result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
  if (result.error && result.error.status === 401) {
    // try to get a new token
    const refreshResult = await baseQuery('/refreshToken', api, extraOptions)
    if (refreshResult.data) {
      // store the new token
      api.dispatch(tokenReceived(refreshResult.data))
      // retry the initial query
      result = await baseQuery(args, api, extraOptions)
    } else {
      api.dispatch(loggedOut())
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

Everything looks fine at first glance, but my refresh token endpoint expects the method to be `PUT`, not `GET`.

How can I perform a `PUT` request inside this function after receiving a `401 Unauthorized` response, using `fetchBaseQuery` as provided by React Toolkit Query (RTK Q) library?

I also store my token in local storage, while the RTK Q example stores the token in redux state. Not sure if this is relevant information, but still.

I tried changing the example to use native `fetch()` after checking for the `401` error, and it works almost fine. I am receiving a new token and swapping it out, but for example when I refresh the page after the token expired, it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 7):

`baseQuery` is just the same wrapper around `fetch` as `fetchBaseQuery` is - and it works similarly to how you use `fetchBaseQuery` throughout your app - usually by returning something from the `query` function, here by calling it directly.

So just like these two are equivalent:

```js
query(){
  return 'https://example.com'
}
//or
query(){
  return { url: 'https://example.com', method: 'GET' }
}
```

also these two are equivalent:

```js
await baseQuery('/refreshToken', api, extraOptions)

//or
await baseQuery({ url: '/refreshToken', method: 'GET' }, api, extraOptions)
```

based on that information you can of course also swap in a `PUT` in there and add whatever you want.

While *usually* it is recommended against storing a refresh token *anywhere in JavaScript* and it is best practice to have an access token in a `httpOnly` cookie (that JavaScript cannot access) that is only exchanged between server and client, of course you can also access localStorage in that function you have there and read your refresh token from localStorage - just like you would do in any other JavaScript code. Just be advised that it is generally considered a security bad practice to store a refresh token in a JavaScript-accessible way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    
const refreshResult = await baseQuery(
  {
    url: '/refreshToken',
    method: 'POST',
    body: {
      refreshToken: localStorage.getItem('refreshToken'),
    },
  },
  api,
  extraOptions
);
```

It works on my machine, thanks @phry for the details